# How to add someone's css project to mine

Tags: html, css, github

I have found this button style on Github and tried to put it in my project by cloning the file and add it to my project css folder, and add

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bttn.css"></script>
<link type="text/css" src="css/dist/bttn.min.css">
```

on the head of HTML file, but when i paste this to my body:

```
<button class="bttn-material-circle bttn-md">
  <i class="icon-menu"></i>
</button>
```

It didn't show up anything.

Can i ask why and how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot for helping beginner like me!

Comment: You need to import the CSS using `<link>` tag

Comment: i used it, you can see above

Comment: Make sure you use the correct class name as used inside the linked css file

Comment: Any errors in your console., is the css loaded?

Comment: As already pointed out you are loading one of those 2 CSS files incorrectly, even comparing it to the other gives you a hint one of them is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling a CSS file in the script tag and reverify the path of CSS that you are using